# Matching the First Values of two columns in new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having problem setting up log in excel.
I have this data from restaurant. Which includes

```
Date | Time | Table Number |Checkin Time | Bill Number | Order Quantity | ... | .......
```

I am trying to calculate the  Checkin Time ( Column D) 
From First "Time" to Same Table Number and Same Bill Number.
Here is the screenshot attached.
[image: Screenshot]

Here in Screenshot you can see the 1st time (b24) is 18:05:13 
Now I want that time to D24 cell till the Blue marker of Column C and E .
I tried the following

```
=IF(AND(E24=E23,C24=C23,A24=A23),D23,MIN(OFFSET(E24,0,-3,MATCH(0,(E24:E$15973=E24)*(C24:C$15973=C24)*(A24:A$15973=A24),0)-1,1)))
```

It does the same thing, But as same table number and same bill number is repeated at the bottom, the time changes, same time doesnt show up. It shows new time.
Here is the link for excel file too. Sheet is TRN .
Please help me.
I can do it manually but Its about 1 months data. and will take forever doing one by one. [excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13WrR9R-7GjL9u7ZyXLDTM3QtXuGhDoHD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

Create a new column, Using your spreadsheet, I've added it as M. Concatenate the three criteria columns here with the formula A&B&C = either do it as an array, or in M2 put `=A2&C2&E2`, then copy down.

Now in the column N, put the following formula at N2 and copy down: `=MINIFS(B:B,M:M,M2)`

Job Done.

Comment: I did the exact you told to do , but it gave me 0:00:00 from 1st row... Only some of the rows shows time, but thats incorrect too. :(

Comment: Did you set the format of the cell to the time format?

Comment: Thank you. I was mistaken. I placed the code in wrong cell instead of N2. because my filtered was on. Thank you again